# Finding difference between .RAW/QCOW images and partition

Tags: qemu, partition, chroot, raw

Are there any available tools for locating the filesystem differences between an image (.RAW) and the image when written to a partition.

In other words, given a `image.raw` if I write that image to a partition with something like `dd if=image.raw of=/dev/sdaX` can I later find what files have been changed on the partition.